# What does deliver higher transfer speed for Timemachine backup to ubuntu? NFS or AppleTalk (netatalk)?

Tags: network, time-machine, backup

I want to do Time Machine backups to an ubuntu server. It is a hosted remote machine, not in my LAN.

So far, I have found two approaches to realize the connection between the computer and the backup server: [netatalk](http://www.fiz-ix.com/2012/12/apple-filing-protocol-afp-file-server-on-ubuntu-using-netatalk/) or [NFS](http://blog.mediafederation.com/andy-hawkins/mac-os-x-time-machine-via-nfs-on-linux-ubuntu-complete-guide-fixes-error-13-etc/). Question is: which of these approaches would deliver higher transfer speed?

I will communicate with the ubuntu server within a ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

NFS is known for higher performance than AFP or SMB; it is also a native protocol for unix based operating systems therefore it should be easier to setup.

Comment: ANy figures on this - also setting up smb or AFS is as easy now, all 3 are network protocols none, NFS was first written on a Unix but no reason why it is easier to setup

Comment: Please have a look at this: http://www.readynas.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=11211

Comment: Put the info in the answer then - not just a link especially not in comments and that does not support your answer it says -In my opinion, AFP is the clear winner; it's cached much better by an OS X client, with significantly better read performance even if it does have to cross the network.

Comment: ALso how does this affect Time Machine, I don't think disk access is the only possible speed difference here

Comment: I am now fighting with apple talk, see: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84966/how-to-increase-local-cache-for-appletalk-macos-ubuntu-with-netatalk, I wonder whether NFS is not a better solution. There is a bug in NFS client of MacOS according to this discussion: http://supercolony.gluster.org/pipermail/gluster-users/2013-February/035422.html . Maybe, it is not so bad.